# How to use multiple distinct on statements in Postgres while retaining the correct order

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct-on

I have a table with weather forecasts in Postgres that looks like this

[image]

Here, a wind and a solar forecast is published every 15 minutes for the same time. I wish to select the latest wind and solar forecast from this table using a `distinct on()` statement. However, when I use this only on the `time` column, it deletes the wind forecast since that forecast is dumped one minute before the solar forecast. I have tried using `distinct on(time, forecast)` but then the order somehow is messed up and I no longer take the latest `dump_date` (see below)

[image]

How can I use a `distinct on()` statement on multiple columns while still retaining the order? The query I'm using now is

```
select
    distinct on ("time", "forecast") *
from table
order by "time"
```

It is important that this query stays dynamic, so hardcoding the `dump_date` is not an option for me.

Comment: Please don't add images. It makes it extremly complecated to copy your test data. Please add some sample data and expected output as copyable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add `dump_date DESC` to the `ORDER`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (time, forecast)
    *
FROM t
ORDER BY time, forecast, dump_date DESC
```